# http request fails to other computer of same network

Tags: php, linux, apache

i am new in linux networking and apache server configuration.

someone gave me two linux server under same vpn. Redhat is installed on them.

those server has both internal ip and external ip. i mean external ip are forwarded to those internal ips.

i have installed apache on those server and also uploaded php websites on them. so i can access website installed on those server from internet(from outside of the vpn) using their external ip.

both server has hostname(i mean i get a local domain name by the hostname command)

and also from ssh i can ping one another by both external ip and internal ip and that hostname.

but from the php end of the installed website i can't access the website of one server from another server.

i have tried with file_get_contents and curl to access websites. i have tried with both external ip and internal ip and hostname but all fail.

i checked the both file_get_contents and curl and found those are working with other public websites like google dot com etc.

but its not working only when i am trying access from one server to another on that vpn(i mean same network)

can you please tell me what is the problem?

is it apache configuration problem or vpn setup or ip forwarding problem?

please help.

Regards
Al Amin

===

## edit

`sudo netstat -tlpen` :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          615968     574/snmpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27         1948058    3881/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         3052927    6927/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          616002     586/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         3052932    6927/named
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          3149386    7369/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                        LISTEN      25         3052929    6927/named
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          616004     586/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      25         3052933    6927/named
```

Comment: Have you tried curl or wget on the command line? Try to use the IP instead of the hostname in PHP. Does it work?

Comment: wget with internal ip show 200 OK but no content. curl is same no content.

Comment: I guess there is an error in the remote php code

Comment: and when i try with external ip it shows failed: no route to host

Comment: but when i browse this server using external ip from internet(out of the vpn) then it shows the site correctly. problem is only from one server to another of same vpn

Comment: Show your apache vhost config

Comment: in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file there are following setup : Listen 80  and <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName avatar-books.ibacstel
</VirtualHost>  and DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" and <Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>

Comment: show output of `sudo netstat -tulpen` (edit the question, not as a comment)

Comment: please check edit section for sudo netstat -tulpen

Comment: Looks like apache is listening on IPv6 only. I miss `0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: how to solve this? i am not expert, please help.

Comment: Try `VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80` in your httpd.conf and restart apache

Comment: i removed other vhost only keeping 0.0.0.:80 but its still not working. do i need to change the Listen 80 also?

Comment: You have just three `0.0.0` need four `0.0.0.0`.. (not sure but would do so).. No, the `Listen 80` is ok. Search for `NameVirtualHost *:80` and change it to `NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80`. However this are just workarounds to see if it works in general

Comment: yes i placed 0.0.0.0:80 in conf file, sorry for mistake here. but still not working

Comment: Have no idea how to help further. Guess it is a Redhat system. Would post in their forums

Comment: finally i found the problem and solved. i just placed Allow from all in <Directory> tag in httpd.conf file and it worked. its my mistake. i was thinking if Deny from all not present in <Directory> tag then by default it will allow all but i was wrong. i had to put the Allow from all in <Directory> tag in httpd.conf file.

Comment: Oh, hadn't this in mind. Nice to hear that it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the problem and solved. i just placed Allow from all in  tag in httpd.conf file and it worked. its my mistake. i was thinking if Deny from all not present in  tag then by default it will allow all but i was wrong. i had to put the Allow from all in  tag in httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a firewall issue. You need to disable the firewall on the server you are trying to connect to. If that fixes it, then reconfigure the firewall to allow VPN connections between the servers.

Comment: i have stopped filewall using following command # service iptables save
# service iptables stop
# chkconfig iptables off but its still not working

Comment: ping or telnet connection works between these two server but not working http request

Comment: I mean running curl on the server. That is what you meant, right?

Comment: finally i found the problem and solved. i just placed Allow from all in <Directory> tag in httpd.conf file and it worked. its my mistake. i was thinking if Deny from all not present in <Directory> tag then by default it will allow all but i was wrong. i had to put the Allow from all in <Directory> tag in httpd.conf file.

Comment: @AlAmin you should post that as an answer and accept it, that will both close the question and help future visitors to this page.